# how do i display user-data and user-id in google analytics report

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have turned on the userid policy in google analytics It provides me the

```
 ga('set', 'userId', {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id. and i am using the codeigniter to get the userid from session

    <script>      
    ga('create', 'UA-98432350-1', 'auto');
    <?php

    if (isset($user_id)) {
      $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-98432350-1', 'auto', {'userId': '%s'});";
     echo sprintf($gacode, $user_id);
     }     
    ?>

    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'its the dimension value');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

this is the code i have used

after applying this code user-explorer in Audience Tab is still showing the ClientId it is not showing userId.

I also want to get the user custom data in reports like its name, email etc. for that I have created custom dimension and right now sending hard coded value 
    however it is not showing anywhere?

[image]

Comment: Storing personally identifiable data like names, addresses etc in Google Analytics violates Google's Terms of Service (and as per ToS they can terminate your account if you do so).  And custom dimension do not show up in standard reports, you can use them is segments, filters and as secondary dimension (the latter two do not apply to user explorer) or in custom reports.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the UserID function in your Google Analytics Backend before you can use it:

1. Log in to your GA Account and go to "Admin"
2. Select the Property and click on "Tracking Info" -> here is the User-ID functionalty
3. Activate the User-ID

It seems, that you have the same problem with you custom dimensions. If you send custom dimensions (or custom metrics) to GA you first have to set up the dmension (or metric) in your GA Backend:

Admin -> Select Property -> Scroll down to "Custom Dimensions" in the Property column.

But you are not alowed to send data, that can identify a user to GA - this can cause a GA barrier.